# Is "Zielerreichungsgrad" a word that is used in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm currently writing my thesis in English, and my professor told me that the German word "Zielerreichungsgrad" (Degree of goal achievement) is used in English.

Can anyone tell me if that's correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *my professor told me* What is he a professor of? What is his subject - what area of study does the thesis concern?

Comment: I don't even know how to pronounce this word.

Comment: Never heard/read it before.

Comment: I've never seen it used, but it's it's become popular lately to borrow German words like _schadenfreude_ and _Backpfeifengesicht_. I suppose that the German penchant for slapping a bunch of existing words together to create a new one is part of the appeal.

Comment: @Greybeard The subject is a value-analysis of different cloud providers. The result of the study is the degree of goal achievement.

Comment: There is no trace of the word on UK websites. There are a lot of hits on German websites. I would not use it in a thesis written in English.

Comment: You seem to have misspelt the word; it should be _Zielerreichungsgrad_. (_Erreichung_ has two r's.) That doesn't help people looking it up and trying to help you. Nevertheless, you shouldn't use it in English.

Comment: I like German as a language and am aware of German words, and yet I have neither heard it nor seen it. It is not part of my *Lebenserfahrung* or of  the present *Zeitgeist*.

Comment: I tried pronouncing it . . . . and I am still wiping up afterwards. It is definitely _not_ going to be popular.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul No worries! German’s always pronounced just like it’s spelt. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm currently writing my thesis in English, and my professor told me
> that the German word "Zielereichungsgrad" (Degree of goal achievement)
> is used in English.
>
> Can anyone tell me if that's correct?

I'm sure it is **not** correct. On searching for the term I got only German sites - either in German or auto-translated to English.

I surmise that most English people (including me) would not know how to pronounce it and, even if we knew in theory, would find it impossible to actually say. It has too many syllables to transfer easily. I can easily say Zeitgeist, Schadenfreude is okay and I can just about manage Entschuldigung if I concentrate. "Zielereichungsgrad" would be completely beyond me without a lot of practice.

Of course there is a possibility that some specialists understand it and use it in academic papers in written form  but 99.9% of English speakers* will have no idea what it means.

---

*Excluding  people who have German as a second language.

Comment: Tsk! No wonder you're finding it difficult to pronounce, there's an obvious typo. It should be double "r" in Ziele**rr**eichungsgrad. Deary, deary me :))